# Generate all cubes with a given volume

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, brute-force, cubes

I need to generate all possible `(a, b, c)` such as, `a * b * c = V`, where V is `function parameter`.

Is there some right way to complete my task? I try use full brute-force by `a, b, c`, but It is very slow. It is due to the fact, that `V` may be more than `10^4`.

P.S. `a, b, c` is integer numbers.

Comment: Assuming by "cubes" you mean "rectangular prisms": Impossible, there are an infinite number of solutions. Ex. for V=1, there's (1,1,1), (1,2,1/2), (1,3,1/3), (1,4,1/4), (1,5,1/5)... Continuing forever.

Comment: Assuming you want integer solutions, then factorise V into a product of primes and consider how to distribute the primes between a,b,c.

Comment: @Kevin, yes I mean rectangular prisms. I am sorry, but I need only integer `a, b, c`.

Comment: Brute force is still feasible for values of V around 10^4. Are you using three nested for loops or two?

Comment: @Kevin, I use 3 loops with `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing something like this:

```
def prisms(V):
    for a in range(1, V+1):
        for b in range(1, V+1):
            for c in range(1, V+1):
                if a*b*c = V:
                    print a,b,c
```

You can reduce the complexity from O(N^3) to O(N^2) by deriving the value of C from the already-known values of A and B.

```
def prisms(V):
    for a in range(1, V+1):
        for b in range(1, V+1):
            if V % (a*b) == 0:
                c = V / (a*b)
                print a,b,c
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it's simple and may be good enough for values of V around 10**4.

Comment: You could also reduce the range of b to `range(a, int((V / a) ** .5) + 1)`.

Comment: @recursive, your reduction helps me. Thank you!